# Integrate Salesforce and AdWords Conversion Tracking into wpcf7

Tags: wordpress, salesforce

i'm tracking AdWords Conversion through a WPCF7. Since on_sent_ok doesen't work anymore, I found a workaround:

```
// Contact Conversion-Tracker
function mycustom_wp_footer() {
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    location = 'example.com./thank-you/';
  }, false );
</script>

<?php
}
```

Now there is a function in my functions.php where I send requests via the wpcf7 to salesforce:

```
// Lead 2 Salesforce
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'editData' );
function editData( $cf7 ) {

$submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

if ( $submission ) {

  $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
  $first_name = $posted_data["Vorname"];
  $last_name = $posted_data["Nachname"];
  $Tel = $posted_data["Tel"];
  $mobile = $posted_data["mobile"];
  $email = $posted_data["email"];
  $message = $posted_data["message"];


  $post_items[] = 'oid=00000000000';
  $post_items[] = 'first_name=' . $first_name;
  $post_items[] = 'last_name=' . $last_name;
  $post_items[] = 'email=' . $email;
  $post_items[] = 'phone=' . $Tel;
  $post_items[] = 'mobile=' . $mobile;
  $post_items[] = 'description=' . $message;

  $post_items[] = 'lead_source=Contact form';
  $post_items[] = 'company=not there';
  $post_items[] = 'Anliegen__c=​Contact';
  $post_items[] = 'Work together';

  $post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);
  // Create a new cURL resource
  $ch = curl_init();

  if (curl_error($ch) != "")
  {
    // error handling
  }

  $con_url = 'salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead? 
  encoding=UTF-8';
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $con_url);
  // Set the method to POST
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  // Pass POST data
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
  curl_exec($ch); // Post to Salesforce
  curl_close($ch); // close cURL resource

}}

// End Lead 2 Salesforce
```

Now these two functins seem to not work together properly. Since I added the first function where the redirect happens, no new leads will be added to my Salesforce.

Thank you in advance.